# Output to file from arraylist not working - java

Tags: java, arrays, file, output

I'm trying to create a program that outputs a bunch of integers from an arraylist to a file, however all I get is a bunch of question marks in the .dat file. Can anyone see what my problem is?

```
   BufferedWriter writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("energy.dat"));
                for(int x = 0; x< energy.size(); x++){
                writer.write(energy.get(x));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            } finally {
                if (writer != null) {
                    try {
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println(e);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `energy` is `List<Integer>` you're calling [`BufferedWriter.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29). This method is not writing a text representation of the number. To write `1` you'd have to call write like this: `writer.write((int)'1')`. This is not the same as `writer.write(1)`.

Replace

```
writer.write(energy.get(x));
```

with

```
String s = String.valueOf(energy.get(x));
writer.write(s, 0, s.length();
```